# Switching from two columns to one column environment and back

Tags: tables, floats, two-column

I am using a two-column template to write an article in LaTeX. 
I would like to insert in the text tables which have one column only. 
Is there a way in which I can switch from a two-column to a one column environment and back?

Comment: `\begin{table*}`

Comment: or `\begin{table}` if it should not take up two columns (\textwidth) and stay in a single column.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- but please note that such a full-width table can appear only at the *top* of a two-column page.  switching back and forth from two-to-one-to-two columns on the same page is possible with the `multicol` package, but not with the `[twocolumn]` option.

Answer (score 1):

The following document shows a full with table (with `table*`) and a table within a single column (with `table`) at the top of a two column page:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|cc|}
\hline
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa& b\\
a&bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{xxxx}
\end{table*}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|cc|}
\hline
aaaaaaaaaaaa& b\\
a&bbbbbb\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{xxxx}
\end{table}

\def\a{abc }
\def\b{\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a}
\def\c{\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b}
\def\d{\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c}
\d\d

\d\d\d

\end{document}
```